# A VBA macro can't get the correct color of a hyperlink in MS Word

Tags: vba, colors, fonts, ms-word, hyperlink

I'm writing a VBA macro that find any font color used except from black (RGB: 0,0,0) and blue.

If this macro finds a character that isn't black and blue in a paragraph, it shows the text of the paragraph with a message box.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim oParagraph As Paragraph, oLink As Hyperlink
    Dim char As Range
    Dim bFound As Boolean, i As Integer
    Dim strHex As String, strHex1 As String, strHex2 As String, strHex3 As String
    Dim strHex4 As String, strHex5 As String
    
    bFound = False
    
    For Each oParagraph In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    
        For Each char In oParagraph.Range.Characters
            strHex = Hex(char.Font.TextColor.RGB)
            strHex1 = Hex(char.Font.ColorIndex)
            strHex2 = Hex(char.Font.Color)
            strHex3 = Hex(char.Style.Font.Color)
            strHex4 = Hex(char.Style.Font.ColorIndex)
            strHex5 = Hex(char.Style.Font.TextColor.RGB)

            If char.Font.Color <> wdColorAutomatic And char.Font.Color <> wdColorBlack _
               And char.Font.Color <> wdColorBlue Then

                bFound = True
                GoTo nt_lb

            End If
        Next char

    Next oParagraph

nt_lb:
    If bFound = True Then
        MsgBox oParagraph.Range.Text
    End If

End Sub
```

But, this macro doesn't work for a hyperlink.

When you execute this macro, this macro shows the pragraph including the hyperlink although the hyperlnk is blue and the remaining text is black in the paragraph.

My macro checks the following properties for getting the correct font color:

- Range.Font.Color
- Range.Font.TextColor
- Range.Style.Font.Color
- Range.Style.Font.TextColor

But, Any of the above properties don't return the correct color (blue).

In the hyperlink text "This is a test link.", this macro finds that the first "T" character isn't black and blue.

[image]

Also, I've attached [a sample document](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmdUOvwK8oRoabiuhqs-Z5x6Tq8?e=Ci0tUc).

Please help me.

Comment: Your link doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I've just updated the attachment link. Please refresh this post and retry it or click this link (http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/attachment.php?attachmentid=29836&d=1654754957).

Comment: That only works if you're logged in on that site...

Comment: Please right click this link and click "Save link as ..." from the context menu on the Chrome browser.

Comment: Only works if you're logged in on that site.

Comment: So sorry @TimWilliams! I've just updated the link, again. Please retry.

Comment: For me, `? char.style.font.textcolor.rgb = vbblue` in the Immediate window gives `True` with the loop stopped on a character in the link

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for your check. If this macro finds any character that isn't blue or black in a paragraph, it stops the loop and processes the paragraph as the invalid.
In "This is a test link.", this macro finds that first "T" isn't blue.

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/49167-vba-macro-cant-get-correct-color-hyperlink.html, http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?69978-I-can-t-get-the-correct-color-of-a-hyperlink & https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/a-vba-macro-cant-get-the-correct-color-of-a/9682060a-3d37-4aec-9618-caed2b9606bd (and who knows how many others). It seems you really don't care how many people waste their time working on essentially the same answer... For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Comment: OK I see that - probably worth pointing out it's only that first "T" in the link that's not seen as blue.  Might be related to the "hidden" HYPERLINK content in that paragraph (try looping over the paragraph from `oParagraph.range.Start` to `.End` and output each character instead of using the `Characters` collection.   The content doing it that way is different: `Test:  HYPERLINK "https://google.com" This is a test link.`